# how to code vector to matrix hamming distance in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, information-retrieval, hamming-distance

I like to develop a query system that finds the most similar items to given one based on a binary signature extracted from the data. I probe for the most efficient way since I have runtime constraints. I tried to use scipy distance but it was too slow. Do you know any other useful library or trick to make it in a faster manner.

For being and example scenario,

I have a query vector with binary values with length 68, and I have a dataset with a matrix size 3000Kx68. I like to find the most similar item in this matrix to given query by using Hamming distance.

thanks for any comment

Comment: One fast method could be storing your 68 bits packed in bytes. Then xor the bytes of the vector and matrix rows and use the result as an index to a lookup table (2^8 entries). The lookup table (simple list) stores the number of bits in each byte. I. e. table[0b111] = 3.

Answer (score 1):

Nice problem, I liked the answers of Alex and Piotr. My first naive attempt resulted also in a solution time around 800ms (on my system). My second attempt, using numpy's `(un)packbits`, resulted in a 4x speed increase.

```
import numpy as np

LENGTH = 68
K = 1024
DATASIZE = 3000 * K
DATA = np.random.randint(0, 2, (DATASIZE, LENGTH)).astype(np.bool)

def RandomVect():
    return np.random.randint(0, 2, (LENGTH)).astype(np.bool)

def HammingDist(vec1, vec2):
    return np.sum(np.logical_xor(vec1, vec2))

def SmallestHamming(vec):
    XorData = np.logical_xor(DATA, vec[np.newaxis, :])
    Lengths = np.sum(XorData, axis=1)
    return DATA[np.argmin(Lengths)]  # returns first smallest

def main():
    v1 = RandomVect()
    v2 = SmallestHamming(v1)
    print(HammingDist(v1, v2))

# oke, lets try make it faster... (using numpy.(un)packbits)

DATA2 = np.packbits(DATA, axis=1)
NBYTES = DATA2.shape[-1]

BYTE2ONES = np.zeros((256), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(0,256):
    BYTE2ONES[i] = np.sum(np.unpackbits(np.uint8(i)))

def RandomVect2():
    return np.packbits(RandomVect())

def HammingDist2(vec1, vec2):
    v1 = np.unpackbits(vec1)
    v2 = np.unpackbits(vec2)
    return np.sum(np.logical_xor(v1, v2))

def SmallestHamming2(vec):
    XorData = DATA2 ^ vec[np.newaxis, :]
    Lengths = np.sum(BYTE2ONES[XorData], axis=1)
    return DATA2[np.argmin(Lengths)]  # returns first smallest

def main2():
    v1 = RandomVect2()
    v2 = SmallestHamming2(v1)
    print(HammingDist2(v1, v2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if there was a significantly faster way than this: Put your data into a pandas DataFrame (`M`), each vector by columns, and your target vector into a pandas Series (`x`),

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rows = 68
columns=3000 
M = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(rows,columns)>0.5)
x = pd.Series(np.random.rand(rows)>0.5)
```

then do the following

```
%timeit M.apply(lambda y: x==y).astype(int).sum().idxmax()

1 loop, best of 3: 746 ms per loop
```

**Edit:** Actually, I am surprised this is a much faster way

```
%timeit M.eq(x, axis=0).astype(int).sum().idxmax()

100 loops, best of 3: 2.68 ms per loop
```

Comment: Oops, Erogol mentioned 3000K columns instead of 3000.

Comment: My second method, with 3000K columns gives me a time of 2.7s per loop, a factor of 1K. This means that evaluations of function DataFrame.eq() for different columns are not parallelized. Perhaps there are ways to force it. Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

Use `cdist` from SciPy:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
Y = cdist(XA, XB, 'hamming')
```

> Computes the normalized Hamming distance, or the proportion of those vector elements between two n-vectors u and v which disagree. To save memory, the matrix X can be of type boolean

Reference: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html

Comment: It was not obvious which distance function from SciPy you tried. If this one, I am afraid you need to resort to some heuristics (if you want 3M x 3M matrix, it is hundreds of terabytes - so you need to parallelize it with Spark or something like that).

Comment: this gives 823ms per call on average which I need at most 20ms

Comment: @Erogol If you parallelize it, do it per batch, not per each vector pair. (I don't know, per 1000?) There is large overhead for conversion for small arrays. Still 823ms per call seems to be huge (I have no idea why it takes so long; it's like you were loading all libraries each run or something.)